# Can we plot RSI on separate chart but MA on main chart using single pinescript code on Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to plot Moving averages on main chart but RSI on separate chart below the main chart simultaneously using single pinescript code on Trading view. Is it possible?

I tried multiple codes that appeared on ChatGPT like the following functions :

- rsi_chart = new_overlay_window(title="RSI")
- new_panel = new("My Indicator", overlay=false)
- rsiPanel = new TradingView.widget(
- "RSI Panel",
- true,
- widget.RSI(),
- "Current Ticker",
- "1D",
- on_chart_id=1
- )

But nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only draw in one window. Multi `overlay` is not supported.